# MVC 5 sorting and filtering data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

On my view I have possibility to filter displayed data using `Ajax.BeginForm` that returns partail view and refreshes only a table with data. I also have a possibility to sort by column when clicking a column header using `Ajax.ActionLink`. The problem is that when I use `Ajax.ActionLink` I have to refresh whole page and I loose what was selected in filters (they are custom multiselect combo controls) so whole data is sorted and displayed.

I tried using `ViewBag` to send Json data to set back the filters but I failed. I would rather only refresh table even on sort. I am kind of new to MVC.
How to do it in a nice way? Thanks for the help!

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions() {HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "exposureRecords"}))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="brands-select" name="brands" multiple="multiple">
            @{
                var brands = Model.Brands;

                foreach (var item in brands)
                {
                    <option value="@item">@item</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    (...similar for 3 other filters...)
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
               @Html.ActionLink("Marka", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.BrandSortParam })
            </th>
            <th>
               @Html.ActionLink("Dyscyplina", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DisciplineSortParm })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Miesiąc", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.MonthSortParm })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Liczba ekspozycji", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.QuantitySortParm })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Ekwiwalent reklamowy", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ValueSortParm })
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
@Html.Partial("_Table",Model)
```

then in controller I have

```
   public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<string> brands, IEnumerable<string> disciplines,
        IEnumerable<string> months,string sortOrder)
    {
        ViewBag.BrandSortParam = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "brand_desc" : "";

        ViewBag.DisciplineSortParm = sortOrder == "discipline" ? "discipline_desc" : "discipline";

        ViewBag.MonthSortParm = sortOrder == "month" ? "month_desc" : "month";

        ViewBag.QuantitySortParm = sortOrder == "quantity" ? "quantity_desc" : "quantity";

        ViewBag.ValueSortParm = sortOrder == "value" ? "value_desc" : "value";


        model.ExposureRecords = FilterExposure(brands, disciplines, months);
        model.ExposureRecords = Sort(sortOrder, model.ExposureRecords);
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView("_Table", model);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: One way to do this would be to render the View on the server side and return the markup in a property of the model. Your links would need to update a hidden field related to your model property to hold your sorts and then call the the form's submit to fire your AjaxForm. You would have to show your view on the AjaxForms.Success by injecting the Model.HtmlMarkup into a <div> tag or something.

Comment: I realize you want to sort using an Action Link, but perhaps you could raise the bar by sorting on the client side with jQuery? check out: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: Thanks! I haven't thought about that. That also solved my other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a client-side library. Sorting can be done in the controller, but in my experience, it is usually painful. I recently did what you're looking to accomplish in a project using [sorttable.js](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#ajaxtables), although there are several options to choose from (see Porschiey's comment above).

To use sortable, add the "sortable" class to your table. Also, be sure to run the "makesortable" js using the OnComplete property in your ajax.beginform ajaxoptions, that way the table will sort after an ajax call. Like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions() {HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "exposureRecords", OnComplete="makesortable"}))
{
...
}

function makesortable() {
sorttable.makeSortable(document.getElementById('exposureRecords'));
};
```